# How would residents of Central Slovakia travel to seaports in 1880's?

Tags: travel

How would residents of Central Slovakia in 1880s travel to northern departure points like Hamburg in order to board Ships to the US ?

Comment: The title is referring to travel in Slovakia and Hungary but the body of the question is asking about travel from Europe to the US, can you clarify what you're asking about?

Comment: Most "average residents" in Europe still walk. If you're planning on making a run for steerage you still would probably just walk there...even back then.

Comment: Related: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/11813/finding-railroad-maps-for-germany-in-late-19th-century

Comment: changed my question

Comment: I think it is now clear. vote to reopen.

Comment: Related: http://www.bridgebetweennations.com/emigration.htm

Answer (score 3):

For travel in their immediate area, they'd walk. Ordinary people did a *lot* less long-distance travel then than nowadays.

For the journey to Hamburg, they'd use the railways. The [Košice–Bohumín Railway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ko%C5%A1ice%E2%80%93Bohum%C3%ADn_Railway) would likely be the most local service, and opened in 1872. The [Bratislava to Vienna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bratislava#History) line opened in 1848, and the [Warsaw-Vienna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw%E2%80%93Vienna_railway) line in 1845. Part-way along the line to Warsaw, at what is now Olderberg, one changes onto the [William Railway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rail_transport_in_Poland#William_Railway) for Berlin. From there, one takes the [Berlin-Hamburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin%E2%80%93Hamburg_Railway) railway to Hamburg.